# Can I export a hair simulation as alembic cache but already converted to geometry?

Tags: rendering, particles, hair, cache

I am trying to deal with particle hair in blender lately and I was wondering how I could manage rendering out a hair simulation. I am not rendering on my local machine, I use external services like sheepIt or other renderfarms. That's why I need to bake and cache the hair simulation before I actually start to render. I know I can export my hair sim as an alembic cache, but if I do so al I get is simulated curves but no geometry..

What is the common workflow on rendering dynamic hairs?

Thanks in advance